# How to automate Mocha tests with Jenkins?

Tags: testing, jenkins, mocha.js

So I have set up a github project and linked it to Jenkins but whenever I execute a build attempt it says in the console:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\SYS-ictlab>mocha
'mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What did I miss?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

If you have executed an `npm install` as part of your CI stage prior to this, and you have mocha added as a (dev) dependency in your `package.json` then you can invoke the mocha binary file as follows

```
node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

You are attempting to invoke the command as if it has been 'linked' so it is accessible globally, this is only doable after running `npm install -g mocha`. This may not be doable in all CI environments, so the above solution is more common.

Comment: It gives me ''.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.' now

Comment: Try it with the `node` command prefacing it as i just edited the command.

Comment: I just did, and now it says: 'module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './formats'' '

Comment: This is likely an issue with your code, not mocha. Line 471 of module.js contains an error

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering this same exact error and I solved it by adding "npx" in front of the command. Example:

```
npx mocha test-file.js
```

My tests were running fine from a command prompt at the same location as the Jenkins build,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project-name>mocha test-file.js
```

but I would get the 'mocha' is not recognized... error message when actually running the build in Jenkins. Adding the npx in front solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar situation, it was throwing `'mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command` even though I ran `npm install` so, I changed the Jenkins configuration file.

In configuration file, under build section, give this command, it will work without throwing any error. (assuming your `package.json` has valid mocha run command)

```
npm install
chmod 777 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha
npm uninstall mocha && npm i mocha
npm test
```