# Azure functions testing and deployment from Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-functions

I am looking for some information on Azure functions. I have developed few functions in NodeJS and would like to use Jenkins to do some testing on it and then deploy it to Azure. Are there any references/docs for this?

Specifically, I would like to know if there are any examples of testing done on Azure functions using Jenkins.

Comment: have you looked into the Azure Functions Jenkins plugin? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+Function+Plugin

Comment: I can use this plugin for deploying to Azure cloud. But what about unit test nodeJS functions on jenkins ??

Comment: Ah, unit testing is just like normal. Nothing official out there for that. Something like using Mocha and running tests like you normally would in Jenkins - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109883/how-to-automate-mocha-tests-with-jenkins